# Lower battery life with Ubuntu than with Windows 10

Tags: graphics, power-management, lenovo, battery, amd-graphics

If I use Windows 10 on my laptop, the battery charge lasts a long time, but if I use Ubuntu 16.04, the battery is used very quickly.

Why is that?

Details:

1. I've installed TLP and indicator-cpufreq on my laptop.
2. My laptop is a Lenovo g510
3. I've disabled the AMD Radeon graphics card and I'm using only the Intel graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a laptop computer, I would be very surprised to find that it has two graphics cards.  First of all, there are no expansion slots for cards.  Second, it will only have one graphics processor on board.  Please recheck what you're meaning with "graphics cards".

Perhaps you meant graphics drivers.  In any case, your particular computer has an Intel® HD Graphics 4600 processor.  Make sure the operating systems **both** recognize it and have the correct driver installed.

The first thing to do is to go into windows and check the power-saving settings.  Write them down.  Then boot into Ubuntu, and check that the settings in TLP are the same as you wrote down from windows.

Restart your computer and see what happens then.  It may be a process of elimination of differences.  Try this as your first step in finding the difference.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for reply, when i'm write the comment to you, the battery it's down from 85% to 78% it's very very quickly used, and i'm deleted windows 10, please solved my problem, thank you .

Comment: One cannot do proper diagnosis if things change.  If you do not have windows installed any longer, there is no longer any comparison.  You should at least allow the battery to go dead and then recharge it before booting up the computer.  Then see if the readings change with the OS recognizing a full charge to begin with.